# Questions regarding a demonstration of photoelectric effect

Tags: electrostatics, photoelectric-effect

I would like you to refer to this video for the question

https://youtu.be/v-1zjdUTu0o

I have a few questions regarding the demonstration

1) Can I use a zinc plate extracted from a heavy duty battery.

2) Can I use conduction instead of induction as shown in video to charge the zinc plate. I will be using a PVC pipe rubbed with a paper towel to transfer negatively charge by contact.

3) Instead of the large ultraviolet source shown in the video, I would be using a small violet light torch shown in the picture, would it also work

[image]

(It's violet even though it looks blue, I think it's 430 nm wavelength.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Zinc from a heavy duty battery, or from a D battery (alkaline or zinc-carbon) should be fine.

2) It is possible to charge the zinc plate negatively by touching is with a rubbed pvc pipe.

3) No, the violet light torch on your photo is probably LED light with a wavelength of about 400 nm. For zinc you would need photons with a wavelength shorter than 290 nm, the threshold wavelength. This is in the dangerous UV-C range, light torches with UV-C emitting LEDs are probably not available as consumer products. May be it is possible to get a mercury lamp emitting low intensity 254 nm light (for germicidal purposes, or for detecting fluorescence of minerals), like the one in this [demo of the photoelectric effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO38qVDGgqw).

Comment: Could a UV lightbulb present in water purifier tanks do the job?

Comment: Yes, if it is a 254 nm mercury lamp. Why, didn't you like the idea of using low intensity? A 50 W ultraviolet lightbulb powered by the mains is able to emit more light than a 5 W battery powered UV lamp, but it is more hazardous too.

Comment: There's a serious lack of good hardware material in my city and my country's Amazon and therefore I can only find those water purifier lamps